# Same solution, different words

Tags: discussion, answers

I've been posting an answer to a question, proposing reasons and procedures to refractor OP code and move part of the logic from the client to the server.

9 minutes later, another user posted an answer with the **exact** same solution rephrased with different words.

2013-09-10 09:20:37Z User
2013-09-10 09:11:34Z Me

Am I supposed to complain? Am I supposed to flag it or not? Is this common/accepted practice?

Comment: You mean Jack's answer? How is it exactly the same as your answer?

Comment: Likely post under discussion: [How do I guarantee execution of jQuery Each statement before continuing on?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18714607)

Comment: I sad the "same solution", not the "same answer". Please read my words.

Comment: Also, your posts are licensed under the CC:Wiki license. If your words are copied verbatim, all the copier has to do is provide attribution. *Ideas* are not protected; and if someone else can explain the idea better in their own words, they'll get the votes. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Did I talked about the votes? My 3 questions are completelly different: please read them.

Comment: I am making assumptions about why you think you would want to complain, perhaps. But no, there is nothing to flag here.

Comment: You are making assumptions too: that you were the only one that had the idea, that the other poster could only have gotten the idea by reading your post.

Comment: I didn't make that assumption anywhere in my question. Please read it and tell me where I did that.

Comment: Then why do you ask about complaining or flagging, if not that you feel the other post should not have been posted? You need to explain better; explain **why** you feel that Jack's post is a problem.

Comment: Because there are 2 answers with two identical solutions.

Comment: Why is that a problem? It is the *explanation* of the solution that has value here. Answers compete for the upvotes. If there are multiple versions of the same solution, the best explanation wins. **And that's a great thing**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of the site is to provide the *best* answers to the questions.

More than one answer proposing the same solution is fine. In fact, it is great, because that means that answers compete on clarity and quality. The best answer will receive the most votes, encouraging anyone that wants to receive votes to write the better answer.

As long as the other post is not a verbatim copy of your words without attribution, there is no *rule* against posting another answer to a question.

In other words, don't flag. Don't complain. Vote and/or improve your *own* post to be better still.

Comment: Thanks, I understand and I don't agree with the downvoter (this seems a perfectly legittimate answer to me). Following your reasoning I am allowed to go through all of SO, search for a good answer and repost it with a different explanation. Am I right? I totally ignored this possibility and considered only the content of a question to be important.

Comment: @Saturnix: Yup, if you feel the solution hasn't been explained well, go ahead and post a better answer. Do try to contribute *something*, some people don't like it when you just rehash the words without actually improving anything. Posts can be voted down as well as up.

Comment: I'm missing to understand how that answer in particular has something improved respect of mine but that must be my limitation (even though I don't think it is a matter of opinion). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the site is to provide answers (period)

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/about)]

The best answers (as judged by the community seeing a post) are voted to the top.
The accepted answer is what the asker (original poster) believes is the answer he/she is looking for.

Multiple answers provide an avenue to explain something that only results in one solution,  in an overall broader range both for the original poster and future users.

In this case, it is more likely both you and the other person *started* writing answers at the same time and the other user *finished* their answer nine minutes later (I corrected the difference in your question)

In terms of when this is not the case, personally it comes down to a balance of answers to breadth of explanation.

*As the number of answers increase, does an additional answer provide more explanation in a way that was not already presented?*

If not, then it's fluff (imo) because otherwise each question can have an infinite number of answers and I don't think that is something SE strives for (thus community question restriction as a question reaches an answer limit)

Comment: If I hit the "post" button and then notice someone has posted the same solution I usually delete my post. I won't do that anymore since this is accepted practice. In my case I think the other answer does NOT provide more explanation in a way that was not already presented but, again, if we don't abstract the solution from how it is expressed there could potentially be infinite answers to a single question. More importantely, it becomes just a matter of opinion and no longer facts which I was thinking to be outside of the scope of SO.

Comment: @Saturnix In your case, Jack's solution does broaden the explanation in terms of lock contention and other items.

Comment: @Saturnix: *Some* opinion is allowed; only when a question will **attract** mostly opinion-based answers is that off-topic.